# Cloud SQL Proxy doesn't create Unix Socket on Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: python, macos, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pymysql

I try to open a connection with my MySql DB from my python script. The DB is a MySql 8 instance running on Google Cloud.

For that, I use the Cloud SQL Proxy from Google Cloud.

I correctly created my service account and **everything is working perfectly on my Ubuntu laptop**. The Unix Socket is created when I execute this command :

`./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=my_connection_name -credential_file=path_to_cred_file`

And I can open my connection with my python script.

The problem is when I try to do the same with my Macbook Pro under Mac OSX Catalina :
Since the "/" folder is now read only, I created the "cloudsql" folder under : `/Users/myname/cloudsql` and gave it all the permissions needed.

But, when I execute that script :
`./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/Users/myname/cloudsql -instances=my_connection_name -credential_file=path_to_cred_file`

The proxy is running fine **except it doesn't create the Unix Socket in the folder**

It's then impossible to connect to the db since the socket doesn't exist.

Is there a workaround on Catalina or is it an other problem ?

Comment: Does the following [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#example-invocations) helps? Notice that you can set an absolute path to override `-dir` by using `./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=my-project:my-region:sql-ins-namet=unix:/my/custom/sql-socket &
mysql -u root -S /my/custom/sql-socket`.

Comment: @Agudolive did you manage to fix your issue?